# Texture is not Loading Properly

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm making kind of a graphic engine using OpenGL, but I am having a bit of a problem, the texture is not loading properly, it loads like this:

[image]

While it should load the picture of the "heart" square fully as a square, but some of it is gone, and it kinda vibrates whenever the frames change, I realized if I remove the frames (on screen), it wouldn't get that problem.

Like, what is wrong with that thing?

EDIT: it appears that the problem is caused by shaders on AMD GPUs, I dunnu why and if someone knows what could be causing the problem by that please tell me, also I have a long code don't really know which is causing the problem...

and I tried a different method: I rendered the label on a different layer and it worked :/

Comment: Looks like z-fighting to me. Disable `GL_DEPTH_TEST` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @tkausl no it didn't work :(
btw, I have tried the same code on different computer, and it doesn't show that bug :O

Comment: Does a similar bug happen if you just color the quad a constant color in the shader?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: @k.krol.27 no it doesn't, if I put a constant color instead of a texture it works perfectly...

Comment: If you could post some code of your render loop and where you load your textures that'd be great

Comment: @k.krol.27 well my code is kind of alot of pages XD, like i've got some functions that do the rendering part, but I kinda think it's a shader issue in AMD GPU, is it related to the fragment / vert shaders ?

Comment: @k.krol.27 Okay well I fixed it by making the label render on a different layer XD